# Jmeter-How to capture the time in different format from request is sent till it is updated in Database?

Tags: jmeter

I have an API https://xxxx-1-0-dev.us-e1.io/api/as3 which file send file from aws s3(based on filepath provided) to a target system. In between there are couple of other API involved while sending to target system. API1 (Where we send file) ---> API2----> API3 which actually send file to Target system. I need to measure the time taken from the time we hit the first API1 and till API3 which sends the file to target. Once we hit API1, we get transactionID as response from API1, which will reach to API2 and Once API3 sends the file to target, It will update the status of transactionID to payload submitted in DB. Can i measure the time for each request from the time we hit the request till transaction is updated in DB. My script is sending request to API1 and capturing tid as response that i am storing in Regular expression and querying DB to get the Received time and storing in regular expression.

I have _time() to capture the time before the API call, getting modified date from DB.
SO the _time function is displayed as 122950 and DB 2020-12-30 12:29:50.296. So i am not able to get the different between two timestamps as its not in same format.
I need to get the difference between these two timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date, you're getting from the DB into a [Unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) using [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) like:

```
${__groovy(Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS'\,'2020-12-30 12:29:50.296').getTime(),)}
```

which will give you `1609284590296`

[image]

[__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) should give you something similar

[image]

Once you have these 2 functions results stored into JMeter Variables you can use [__longSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) function to get the delta (it will be in milliseconds)

Comment: Thank you, i need to Dynamically parse the date and time. I am storing the date time in "Modified_date" where as i cannot parse dynamic date and time using the above groovy